# Laravel (5.6) Service Poviders

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have been disabling certain services in my laravel application.

But when I disabled **QueueService** Provider since I was not using queue service and tried running artisan commands it displayed error **"Class queue.listener not found"** can some one tell me where is it (QueueServiceProvider) being used by laravel ?.

The same happens if I disable **TranslationServiceProvider** stating **Class translator not found**. I removed all __() operators from laravel auth scaffoldings and searched for trans() methods in the configs but no progess.

Help needed thank you.

Comment: Could be because Artisan uses `registerDatabaseConnector` function from `QueueServiceProvider` class, not sure about `TranslationServiceProvider`

Comment: Checked that file. As of Laravel 5.6 there's no method named `registerDatabaseConnector` but I found out that somewhere internally artisan command is dependent on `registerListener` `registerManager` `registerWorker` methods in `QueueServiceProvider`. But is it safe if I disabled it in production ? When I won't be needing any artisan command ?.